# CSS background-position for icon only shows me last icon see code for more detail

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my HTML for showing the icon bar of reply, retweet, favorite.

```
<div id="twitter-actions" style="display: none; opacity: 0; margin-top: -20px;">
   <div class="intent" id="intent-reply"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=481493696643608576" title="Reply"></a></div>
   <div class="intent" id="intent-retweet"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=481493696643608576" title="Retweet"></a></div>
   <div class="intent" id="intent-fave"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=481493696643608576" title="Favourite"></a></div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS for showing that bar.

```
#twitter-actions {
    width:75px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:5px;   
    margin-top:3px;
        display:none;
}
.intent {
    width:25px;
    height:16px;
    float:left; 
}
.intent a{
    width:25px;
    height:16px;
    display:block;
    background-image:url(../images/tweet-actions.png);
    float:left; 
} 
.intent a:hover{
    background-position:-25px 0px;
} 


#intent-reply a{
    background-position:0px 0px;
} 
#intent-reply a:hover{
    background-position:-25px 0px;
} 

#intent-retweet a{
    background-position:0px -17px;
} 
#intent-retweet a:hover{
    background-position:-25px -17px;
} 
#intent-fave a{
    background-position:0px -36px;
} 
#intent-fave a:hover{
    background-position:-25px -36px;
}
```

[image: This is my image]

The problem is only last icon appears i couldn't solve problem myself so asking you with as much details i can give you.

[image]

[Updated Example of above HTML and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/V8LPA/3/)

Comment: Can you post a live link? Or maybe try to reproduce this problem on codepen?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/V8LPA/ The HTML and CSS for just the example seems good, you might want to isolate the whole block and see what might be conflicting.

Comment: I generate this html code from j query and it's a php file its a same code I took it from inspect element.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Sure I'll post more details soon  it's strange if it's overriding then it is should be for all element but only reply and retweet is not working. Favourite is working fine.

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/V8LPA/3/

Comment: it looks like browser issue to me because this link just works fine in my mobile showing all 3 button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this still isn't working, I would suggest using your "Inspect Element" feature (available on most modern browsers) to see if any CSS is overriding what you wrote here (It would look like [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/iwritefor/articlefiles/1708-overried-inspection-b0bc591b-6983-436c-bb1b-88d95671ec9b.png)), seeing as isolating the code you provided seems to work just fine.

Additionally, browser plugins can effect the way a page is displayed. Especially ad blockers. Try [running your browser with all your plugins disabled/turned off](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/groups/turn-browser-add-ons-plug-ins-sln3016.html) and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Yup I have tried inspect element feature it isn't override

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? You can message it to me if need be.

Comment: Yup I have tried inspect element feature it isn't overriding if it does it should be for all elements where as favourites is just working fine, thanks for input I'll post whole post html soon .

Comment: Sorry it's local host and currently not accessible by Me. ASAP I can access I'll post it.

Comment: It works in IE and doesn't in chrome and firefox any solution ?

Comment: Your jsfiddle works for me in everything. It's possible that a browser plugin is keeping this from displaying correctly.

Comment: Done. Thanks. Which plugin was causing the problem?

Comment: all plugins are disabled. also using incognito window.